# Div position with inline-block

Tags: html, position, css

I'm trying to make a navigation area, with a div and 4 divs inside it.

I created a list, and set inline-block for those divs class.

But I cant set them to a horizontal position.

I want to have a hidden scroll, and make it moves with jquery, clicking on directional buttons bellow that div.

You can see the problem with the divs position here: http://jsfiddle.net/BRtCg/1/

```
    .divsroll {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#main {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Thanks for the help since now.

Comment: Hey - here's one I made for fun. Pretty much the same as the selected answer, but I tried to fix the issue of double clicking the button messing up the layout. http://jsfiddle.net/NBpUN/ Might be helpful.

Comment: That's nice! I'll try to add that to the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to achieve.

In your CSS, you'll need to set your `ul li` to inline-block and make the width of your `ul` to account for the needed space (the extra 15px accounts for the extra space around the elements):

```
#main ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 2015px;
}
#main ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I also restructured your jQuery code, and the scrolling is now functional (tested in firefox).

HTML changes:

```
<input type='button' value='<<' id="back">
<input type='button' value='>>' id="forward">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#forward').click(function() {
        var leftPos = $('#main').scrollLeft();
        $("#main").animate({scrollLeft: 505 + leftPos}, 'slow');
    });

   $('#back').click(function() {
        var leftPos = $('#main').scrollLeft();
        $("#main").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos - 505}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BRtCg/19/)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do. I tried to remove the list, leaving only the main div, and the others inside. And set inline-block, for the class divsroll. But still in vertical align, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: `divsroll` is a div inside the li elements. setting it to `inline-block` doesn't do anything in this case because it's a child element of the `li`. You have to apply inline-block to the li element itself

Comment: I see. But if I didnt use li, how could I align them horizontally?

Comment: use `float:left` and maybe a `margin-right:` with a few pixels for some spacing between them if necessary

Comment: Got it. Thanks for you attention and help. ^^

Answer (score 0):

i set `float:left` for the `<li>` `<div>` tags.

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/BRtCg/14/